# query case with Laravel and Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Simply , I want to fetch products with certain size from the DB

each product has sizes column : which contains (for example) : "XS,M,L"

I run this statement

```
return DB::table('products')->where([['sizes', 'LIKE', "%".$size."%"]])->paginate(1);
```

for example if $size = "L" , it fetches any product with "L" or "XL" or "XXL" - and that's normal with my statement

I ask now about method to fetch only a certain size

Comment: Did you try `->where('sizes', $size)` ¿

Comment: it may not work - as each product can have multiple sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use store value in separate rows in other table so that it is easy to query.

Although you do it by `find_in_set` with `whereRaw`

```
DB::table('products')
    ->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET('L',sizes)")
    ->paginate(1);
```

Comment: what if I would like to use multiple conditions , I need to use another where condition beside your answer

Comment: then use another `->where()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the exact size then you can try

```
return DB::table('products')->where(['sizes',  $size])->paginate(1);
```

use `=` instead of `Like`.

For more use cases here are the different examples.

```
WHERE sizes LIKE 'L%'   //Finds any values that starts with "L"
WHERE sizes LIKE '%L'   //Finds any values that ends with "L"
WHERE sizes LIKE '%or%' //Finds any values that have "or" in any position
WHERE sizes LIKE '_r%'  //Finds any values that have "r" in the second position
WHERE sizes LIKE 'a_%_%'    //Finds any values that starts with "a" and are at least 3 characters in length
WHERE sizes LIKE 'a%o'  //Finds any values that starts with "a" and ends with "o"
```

You have also a typo in your code

Change this

```
return DB::table('products')->where([['sizes', 'LIKE', "%".$size."%"]])->paginate(1);
```

To this

```
return DB::table('products')->where('sizes', 'LIKE', "%".$size."%")->paginate(1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think no difference between "return DB::table('products')->where([['sizes', 'LIKE', "%".$size."%"]])->paginate(1);" and "return DB::table('products')->where('sizes', 'LIKE', "%".$size."%")->paginate(1);"